Faust-streaming Error in hello_world demo code: object has no attribute 'build_request_header'
Im familiarizing myself with kafka via faust-streaming. I created a python 3.10 env, and a redpanda cluster on localhost:9092. The code I used is the hello world demo presented by the faust-streaming documentation. https://faust-streaming.github.io/faust/playbooks/quickstart.html
import faust

app = faust.App(
    'hello-world',
    broker='kafka://localhost:9092',
    value_serializer='raw',
)

greetings_topic = app.topic('greetings')

@app.agent(greetings_topic)
async def greet(greetings):
    async for greeting in greetings:
        print(greeting)

When I run the application with "faust -A hello_world worker -l info" I recieve the error:

[^Worker]: Error: AttributeError("'CreateTopicsRequest_v1' object has no attribute 'build_request_header'.

I checked if the cluster might be the issue, but an aiokafka setup with a producer/consumer aimed at localhost:9092 seems to run smoothly. Since I cant find any mention of this issue, I'm hoping anyone here can help me get faust-streaming running.

Unfortunate timing is all.
This is a dependency management issue (on faust-streaming's part). Their package (faust-streaming at 0.11.0) allows for any version of aiokafka >= 0.9.0, yet aiokafka just released 0.11.0 two weeks ago.
Just add an upper-limit to your environment to prevent the use of the latest release of aiokafka until faust-streaming is updated.
# Update your requirements file
echo 'aiokafka>=0.9.0,<0.11.0' >> requirements.txt

# Or, just install aiokafka with a version range
pip install 'aiokafka>=0.9.0,<0.11.0'

# Or, if you're using poetry
poetry add 'aiokafka>=0.9.0,<0.11.0'

Edit: I looked on github and found an issue for it which you can track for a resolution: https://github.com/faust-streaming/faust/issues/633#issue-2406150814

I came across this from running an package update in a project where I'm already using faust-streaming.

That did the job! Thanks

Hi, I'm the maintainer of faust-streaming! I got unlucky with the timing of CI/CD builds breaking with aredis tests and a patch was delayed in release. This should be fixed in faust-streaming==0.11.1!

As an aside, Faust is a community-driven project and whilst it’s stable, the support on Stack Overflow appears to be almost non-existent when you look at the faust tag.
There are other open source Python alternatives to Faust worth checking out. I work on Quix Streams and like Faust it's a pure Python alternative, doesn't require a server-side cluster, has good adoption and we’re partnered with Redpanda so we have lots of examples in our repo. There’s a growing team of maintainers and, most importantly, has active community members in the Slack group so responses to support requests are usually very quick. We don't just discuss our own library, so I invite everyone interested in working with Python and Kafka to join regardless of skill level.

I did look at quix streams, however I am not sure if it can help me in my usecase. Basically what I need to create is to look at the latest 5 rows and determine if the middle one is a peak. Is this something quix streams could solve without additional caching?

I looked further into Quix Streaming. I created a poc with Quix and Redis, which was a lot easier than I expected.  On the long it might seems like a better solution... from both the technical and the community support part.

I'm glad you checked it out and found a solution by yourself! That sounds good. I recommend sinking data from Kafka to a database for reporting requirements. However, you can also achieve what you need with stream processing using a stateful function. The streaming dataframe apply() function has a stateful parameter that you can set to True to give you access to a state object, which operates like a dictionary. You can save the latest 5 rows and determine if the max is in the middle index (docs here).
